# angular js onmouseover showhint not show data

Tags: php, angularjs

I have problem with some angular things. I'm trying to set recursive dive with some info with some hintshow (tooltip).

The problem is all information show fine exclusive the hintshow. Added the screen show + some code. The data saved in {{x.who_liked}} as string, for example

"wyd3x, someoneXD, Shohamiko, guymaster, HUBHVNKL, Rauli, Matk, gal350"

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            <div class="post">
                <div class="posterDetails">

                    <a href="?page=profile&player={{x.username}}">{{x.username}}</a></br>
                    פירסם  ב<?php echo timeAgo("{{x.date}}"); ?>
                    <div ng-switch on="x.user_id">
                        <div ng-switch-when="<?=$_SESSION['id']?>">
                            <?php
                            echo " <a style='color:red;' href=\"?page=feeds&id={{x.id}}&delete\">(מחק סטטוס)</a>";
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postContent" ng-bind-html="x.msg | unsafe"></div>
                <div class="options" style="text-align: right;padding: 5px;">
                    <div id="like" style="display:inline-block">
                        <img src="images/{{x.liked}}" post_id={{x.id}} ng-click="like(x)"> {{x.likes}} <div class="liked" onMouseover="showhint('{{x.who_liked}}', this)" style="display:inline-block">אהבו</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="report" ng-click="report(x)" style="cursor: pointer; display:inline-block">
                        <img src="images/icons/vlag.png"> דווח
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[current station](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bmgK.png)

tooltip: http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/showhint.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `{{}}` interpolation inside your `onMouseover` directive.It should be `onMouseover="showhint(x.who_liked, this)"`

or

**Angular solution**

You can fix it like this :

```
ng-mouseover="showhint(x.who_liked,this)"
```

Instead of `onMouseover` , you can use `ng-mouseover`.

For better understanding , see this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGohFqiGKmkonmLwT3g1?p=preview)

Comment: second solution worked. first not bcz the function in php